# How to store Templates in Django 1.11?

Tags: python, django

I have two ways to use templates like this. Which is good in Django 1.11

## 1st way

```
app1/
    templates/
             contact.html
app2/
    templates/
             home.html
             about.html
```

And then in settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1/templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app2/templates')],
        ...
    }
```

## 2nd way

```
app1/
    ...
app2/
    ...
templates/
         home.html
         about.html
         contact.html
```

And then in settings

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {   ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        ...
    }
```

Which is better in arranging templates

Answer (score 0):

1st method is preferred as when you want to reuse `app1`, you can just copy/paste `app1` to your new project.